# google places autocomplete API get town and region (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

I think this is a new question and I have some example code.

The code for google places autocomplete API is:

```
      function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchField');
        var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
        country: ['uk', 'ie']
        }
      };
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', 
      function() {
         var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
         var placeStreet = autocomplete.getPlace()[0];
         var place_ = place.name;
         var lat_ = place.geometry.location.lat();
         var long_ = place.geometry.location.lng();
         alert(place + ", street:  " + placeStreet + ", " + place_ + ", " + 
         lat_ + ", " + long_);

       });
     }
```

How do I get the town or region or country.  As I'm from the UK, I need to detect town such as london, region or county = middlesex and country = United Kingdom.  Is there anyway to do this? and how do I find the printout of getPlace() how do I get the Javascript object printed out.

Thanks in advance

***EDIT JSON.stringify(autocomplete.getPlaces()) prints out the object but how do I extract town, region, country etc.

*** EDIT In my autocomplte my json object prints out objects in different orders so finding the 3 rd object will be postal town or administrative area.   How do I search by type and get type country and the country or type postal_town and town.  My json outputs are:

1)

```
     {
      "address_components": [
      {
      "long_name": "12-20",
      "short_name": "12-20",
      "types": [
       "street_number"
      ]
      },
      {
      "long_name": "Wood Street",
      "short_name": "Wood St",
      "types": [
       "route"
       ]
      },
      {
       "long_name": "Walthamstow",
        "short_name": "Walthamstow",
        "types": [
        "neighborhood",
        "political"
       ]
     },
     {
      "long_name": "London",
      "short_name": "London",
       "types": [
       "postal_town"
      ]
      }, etc
```

2)

```
 {
    "address_components": [
    {
     "long_name": "London",
      "short_name": "London",
     "types": [
      "locality",
      "political"
    ]
   },
   {
  "long_name": "London",
  "short_name": "London",
  "types": [
    "postal_town"
  ]
    },
     {
        "long_name": "Greater London",
        "short_name": "Greater London",
        " types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
       "political"
     ]
     },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant by town and region but you may try the following as i did to get city and state of a selected place

for town you can try : `locality` or `sublocality_level_1` property.If `locality` returns no result use `sublocality_level_1`, I suggest try both

and for region you may try : `administrative_area_level_1`

and for country use : `country`

Here's the api documentation : [place autocomplete api documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types)

**Update :**

Here's what you should do :

1.First you should get the `address_component` from response

```
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace().address_components

    //it will give you an array of objects which has a type property.This type property holds different components of your address.Loop through it to get your desired component

    address_component = [
      {
        "long_name" : "Australia",
        "short_name": "Aus",
        "types" : ["country"]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
        "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "Council of the City of Sydney",
        "short_name" : "Sydney",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
        "long_name" : "New South Wales",
        "short_name" : "NSW",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      }
```

]

you will loop through and find the types you need and get short_name or long _name and show it to the screen.If you understand this, you are good to go.If not  you can ask me .Check all the components available [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)

**CODE :**

***declare a component map which will house the components you want to use only***

```
   var componentMap = {
        country: 'country',
        locality: 'locality',
        administrative_area_level_1 : 'administrative_area_level_1',
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < place.length; i++){

        var types = place[i].types; // get types array of each component 

        for(var j = 0; j < types.length; j++){ // loop through the types array of each component as types is an array and same thing can be indicated by different name.As you can see in the json object above 

              var component_type = types[j];

              // check if this type is in your component map.If so that means you want this component

              if(componentMap.hasOwnProperty(component_type)){


                console.log(place[i]['long_name']);

              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi AL-zami,   so would I use autocomplete.getPlaces()["locality"].   Soz really new to this.

Comment: How would I for example get the country.  How would I navigate through the JSON object?

Comment: check out my updated answer. Ask me if there is any confusion

Comment: instead of alert try to use console.log().Check my updated answer though.I showed how you can navigate through the JSON

Comment: Hi, I showed the 2 JSON outputs I need to select the text where the object with index 2 or index 3 for example is type postal_town

Comment: i updated my code. You don't need to worry about the index position of your desired component.Use a component map object which will help you to extract the components you want to show to screen.

Comment: try the code i have given in your console or fiddle and try to understand the logic behind it.You should be doing it by youself if you want to learn .

Comment: I have done this JSFiddle using the example above.  Is there no simpler way to get locality or town and town?

[Australia example (JSFiddle)][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/fba6b9wr/

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can get city and state:

```
const city = place.address_components.filter(f => JSON.stringify(f.types) === JSON.stringify(['locality', 'political']))[0].short_name;
const state = place.address_components.filter(f => JSON.stringify(f.types) === JSON.stringify(['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']))[0].short_name;
const displayCity = place.address_components.filter(f => JSON.stringify(f.types) === JSON.stringify(['locality', 'political']))[0].long_name;
const displayState = place.address_components.filter(f => JSON.stringify(f.types) === JSON.stringify(['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']))[0].long_name;
```