# How to get consistent City, State and Country values from Places with Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

**Desired Behaviour**

Be able to retrieve City, State (Region) and Country values upon selecting a place from autocomplete search box results.

**Actual Behaviour**

It seems each `Place` may have a different number of values in its `address_components` array, so it's not possible to directly reference City, State and Country by their position in the array.

**Question**

Is there an established convention for easily getting consistent City, State and Country values from Places?

I started creating a nested loop to check the `types` values within the `address_components` array values, but it felt like too much work, and also it seems that values in the `types` array do not need to be unique, eg `type > political` can appear more than once in an `address_components` array.

**What I've Tried**

*Relevant Code*

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=********&libraries=places"></script>
```

```js
// restrict search results to the 'cities' type
// see:  https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?csw=1#table3
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)']
};

// create autocomplete
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

// do stuff when selecting a search result
autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {

const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

console.log("here is the place!");
console.log(place);

});
```

I thought I could get City, State (Region) and Country values like this:

```js
var place_city = place.name;
var place_region = place.address_components[1].long_name;
var place_country = place.address_components[2].short_name;
```

However, the examples below show that places may have `address_components` properties that are structured differently:

Search term:  `Townsville QLD, Australia`

Returns `address_components` as an array of 4 values - country is included as the 4th value:

```js
[
  {
    "long_name": "Townsville",
    "short_name": "Townsville",
    "types": [
      "colloquial_area",
      "locality",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Townsville City",
    "short_name": "Townsville",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_2",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Queensland",
    "short_name": "QLD",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_1",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Australia",
    "short_name": "AU",
    "types": [
      "country",
      "political"
    ]
  }
]
```

Search term:  `Brisbane QLD, Australia`

Returns `address_components` as an array of 3 values - country is included as the 3rd value:

```js
[
  {
    "long_name": "Brisbane",
    "short_name": "Brisbane",
    "types": [
      "colloquial_area",
      "locality",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Queensland",
    "short_name": "QLD",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_1",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Australia",
    "short_name": "AU",
    "types": [
      "country",
      "political"
    ]
  }
]
```

Search term:  `Acton Park TAS, Australia`

Returns `address_components` as an array of 5 values - country is included as the 4th value:

```js
[
  {
    "long_name": "Acton Park",
    "short_name": "Acton Park",
    "types": [
      "locality",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Clarence City Council",
    "short_name": "Clarence City",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_2",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Tasmania",
    "short_name": "TAS",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_1",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "Australia",
    "short_name": "AU",
    "types": [
      "country",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "long_name": "7170",
    "short_name": "7170",
    "types": [
      "postal_code"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You need to process the `address_components` array looking for the `type` you need. 
 See the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are other questions that address this subject, as commented on the original post.

In case it helps anyone else, it was helpful for me to familiarise myself with content here:

[Address types and address component types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#Types)

The link not only lists the different `types`, but provides an explanation of what each means.

In my circumstance, I came to the, hopefully correct, conclusion that I was mainly interested in these types:

- locality (for "City")
- administrative_area_level_1 (for "State")
- country (for "Country")

And my first draft of a newbie friendly nested loop was:

```js
var city = "";
var state = "";
var country = "";

$.each(my_place, function(index_1, value_1) {

    var types = value_1.types;

    $.each(types, function(index_2, value_2) {
        if (value_2 === "locality") {
            city = my_place[index_1]['long_name'];
        } else if (value_2 === "administrative_area_level_1") {
            state = my_place[index_1]['long_name'];
        } else if (value_2 === "country") {
            country = my_place[index_1]['short_name'];
        }
    });

});

console.log("city: " + city);
console.log("state: " + state);
console.log("country: " + country);
```

It seems to work when testing it on each of the `address_components` arrays in the OP.

As pointed out in the comments, there seems to be more sophisticated solutions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47245551).